# How to thread a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have data in format

```
data = {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}, {d1, d2}}
```

Tableform:

[image]

I want to thread it to :

```
tdata = {{{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}}, {{a1, c1}, {a2, c2}}, {{a1, d1}, {a2, d2}}}
```

Tableform:

[image]

---

And I would like to do better then

```
pseudofunction[n_] := Transpose[{data2[[1]], data2[[n]]}];
SetAttributes[pseudofunction, Listable];
Range[2, 4] // pseudofunction
```

---

Here is my benchmark data, where data3 is normal sample of real data.

```
data3 = Drop[ExcelWorkBook[[Column1 ;; Column4]], None, 1];
data2 = {a #, b #, c #, d #} & /@ Range[1, 10^5];
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^6, 4}];
```

Here is my benchmark code

```
kptnw[list_] := Transpose[{Table[First@#, {Length@# - 1}], Rest@#}, {3, 1, 2}] &@list
kptnw2[list_] := Transpose[{ConstantArray[First@#, Length@# - 1], Rest@#}, {3, 1, 2}] &@list
OleksandrR[list_] := Flatten[Outer[List, List@First[list], Rest[list], 1], {{2}, {1, 4}}]
paradox2[list_] := Partition[Riffle[list[[1]], #], 2] & /@ Drop[list, 1]
RM[list_] := FoldList[Transpose[{First@list, #2}] &, Null, Rest[list]] // Rest
rcollyer[list_] := With[{fst = First@#, rst = Rest@#}, Thread[{fst, #}] & /@ rst] &@list

Drop[Timing[paradox2[#];] & /@ {data, data2, data3}, None, -1]
Drop[Timing[OleksandrR[#];] & /@ {data, data2, data3}, None, -1]
Drop[Timing[kptnw[#];] & /@ {data, data2, data3}, None, -1]
Drop[Timing[kptnw2[#];] & /@ {data, data2, data3}, None, -1]
Drop[Timing[RM[#];] & /@ {data, data2, data3}, None, -1]
Drop[Timing[rcollyer[#];] & /@ {data, data2, data3}, None, -1]
```

Results

```
{{7.503}, {0.968}, {0.031}}
{{0.983}, {0.296}, {0.031}}
{{0.312}, {1.67}, {0.031}}
{{0.094}, {0.218}, {0.031}}
{{3.759}, {0.546}, {0.032}}
{{3.073}, {0.733}, {0.031}}
```

Comment: It's interesting that `Table` and `Outer` switch positions in the rankings depending on whether the data are symbolic or numeric. Most likely this shows that different emphases were applied in the optimization of these functions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your lists are long, there are faster approaches using high-level functions and structural operations. Here are two alternatives.

First we try `Outer` and `Flatten`:

```
data = {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}, {d1, d2}};
Flatten[Outer[List, List@First[data], Rest[data], 1], {{2}, {1, 4}}]
```

> ```
> {{{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}}, {{a1, c1}, {a2, c2}}, {{a1, d1}, {a2, d2}}}
> ```

And now `Distribute` and `Transpose`:

```
Transpose[Distribute[{List@First[data], Rest[data]}, List], {1, 3, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}}, {{a1, c1}, {a2, c2}}, {{a1, d1}, {a2, d2}}}
> ```

Evidently, they give the correct result. Now for a `Timing` comparison:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^6, 2}];
```

The timings, in rank order, are:

1. kptnw's `Table`/`Transpose` method: 0.297 seconds
2. `Outer`/`Flatten`: 0.812 seconds
3. `Distribute`/`Transpose`: 0.891 seconds
4. rcollyer's `Thread`/`Map` approach: 2.907 seconds
5. R.M's `Transpose`/`FoldList` method: 3.844 seconds
6. paradox2's solution with `Riffle` and `Partition`: 7.407 seconds

The `Outer`/`Flatten` and `Distribute`/`Transpose` approaches are quite fast, but clearly `Table` is much better-optimized than `Distribute`, since while these two methods are conceptually similar, kptnw's solution using the former is by far the fastest and most memory-efficient. The other solutions, not using structural operations, are considerably slower, which is not unexpected.

Comment: I double checked results - yes, table is of (4 << size < 10^6) and your Outer/Flatten is so far the most efficient in speed/memory.

Comment: kptnw added another method, swapping out `Table` for `ConstantArray` which on my system cuts the time by approx. one-sixth of his `Table`/`Transpose` method.

Comment: @rcollyer it seems to be quite data-dependent. While the `ConstantArray`/`Transpose` method is probably the best overall, Margus's benchmarks show that for symbolic inputs `Outer`/`Flatten` isn't much slower, if at all. I tried to improve on `ConstantArray`/`Transpose`, but I couldn't; if not absolutely optimal, it's very close.

Answer (score 15):

Another approach using `Transpose`:

```
Transpose[{Table[First@#,{Length@#-1}],Rest@#},{3,1,2}]&@data
(* Out[1]= {{{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}}, {{a1, c1}, {a2, c2}}, {{a1, d1}, {a2, d2}}} *)
```

On my pc, it is about 3 times faster than the `Outer/Flatten` approach.

edit:

It seems that the bottleneck is `Table`.By changing it into `ConstantArray`:

```
Transpose[{ConstantArray[First@#,Length@#-1],Rest@#},{3,1,2}]&@data
```

Now it is about 10 times faster than the `Outer/Flatten` approach.

Comment: @kptnw: Good job.

Answer (score 11):

This works:

```
data = {{a1,a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}, {d1, d2}}
With[{fst = First@#, rst = Rest@#}, Thread[{fst, #}] & /@ rst]& @ data
```

> ```
> {{{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}}, {{a1, c1}, {a2, c2}}, {{a1, d1}, {a2, d2}}}
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Try this：

```
data = {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}, {d1, d2}};
Partition[Riffle[First[data], #], 2] & /@ Rest[data]
```

Comment: +1 `Drop[data,1]` can also be expressed as `Rest[data]`

Comment: @David Carraher Yep,in the same way,data[[1]] can also be replaced by First[data],so we get another expression :`Partition[Riffle[First[data], #], 2] & /@ Rest[data]`.I really like this form which looks more graceful than using `Drop` and `Part`,thanks for your advice.

Comment: I agree that it's more easy to comprehend  in the form with `First` and `Rest`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another approach using `FoldList`

```
data = {{a1,a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}, {d1, d2}};
FoldList[Transpose[{First@data, #2}] &, Null, Rest[data]] // Rest
(* Out[1]= {{{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}}, {{a1, c1}, {a2, c2}}, {{a1, d1}, {a2, d2}}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the second and third arguments of `Thread`:

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Thread /@ Thread[{#, {##2}} & @@ #, List, {2}] &;

f@{{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}, {d1, d2}} // TableForm
```

[image]