# Distributing elements across a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists:

```
u = {{1, 3}, {2, 6}, {3, 9}}
v = {0, 4}
```

and I want to obtain this list from them:

```
z = {{{0, 1}, {4, 3}}, {{0, 2}, {4, 6}}, {{0, 3},{4, 9}}}
```

I guess the solution will make use of Map, Thread, or even MapThread but I've tried every combinaison I can think of with no luck. How can I do it?

Comment: You could do something like `Transpose[Thread /@ Thread[{v, Transpose[u]}]]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Comment: Related: [(3070)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3070/121), [(4004)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4004/121), [(11298)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11298/121), [(13748)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13748/121) -- 4004 is an exact duplicate asked in a slightly unusual way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works:

```
Transpose[{v, #}] & /@ u
```

> ```
> {{{0, 1}, {4, 3}}, {{0, 2}, {4, 6}}, {{0, 3}, {4, 9}}}
> ```

Comment: Perfect thanks I didn't think about Transpose

Answer (score 13):

```
Transpose /@ Tuples[{{v}, u}]
Transpose @@@ Table[{j, i}, {i, u}, {j, {v}}]
Transpose /@ Partition[Riffle[u, {v}, {1, -2, 2}], 2]

(*{{{0, 1}, {4, 3}}, {{0, 2}, {4, 6}}, {{0, 3}, {4, 9}}}*)
```

Comment: Another code equivalent to the third code: `Nest[Partition[#, 2] &, Riffle[Flatten[u], v, {1, -2, 2}], 2]`

Answer (score 9):

Another possibility using `Outer`:

```
Outer[Composition[Transpose, List], {v}, u, 1][[1]]

(* {{{0, 1}, {4, 3}}, {{0, 2}, {4, 6}}, {{0, 3}, {4, 9}}} *)
```

---

I also like using `Riffle` for this:

```
Riffle[v, #] ~Partition~ 2 & /@ u
```

Answer (score 9):

Just to be different:

```
Thread /@ ArrayFlatten @ {{v, List /@ u}}

Thread /@ Block[{v}, Thread @ {v, u}]
```

---

Here is a variation of chyanog's method that is the fastest I have tested on a long `u` and short `v`, both packed:

```
Transpose[Tuples @ {{v}, u}, {1, 3, 2}]
```

Timings:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

u = RandomInteger[99, {500000, 7}];
v = RandomInteger[99, 7];

Do[Transpose[{v, #}] & /@ u, {10}]              // timeAvg
Do[Transpose[Tuples@{{v}, u}, {1, 3, 2}], {10}] // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.1342
>
> 0.011104
> ```

And here are a couple of other, slower, methods (but faster than the first two in this answer):

```
Transpose[ArrayFlatten@{{v, {u}\[Transpose]}}, {1, 3, 2}]

With[{T = Transpose},
  T[Tuples /@ T@{T@{v}, T@u}]
]
```

---

`Inner` as used by Artes is superior on unpacked data, and ideal for mixed types.  However, when compared to the methods above on packed data it falls behind:

```
Inner[List, v, Transpose@u, List] // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.2028   (* compare 0.1342 and 0.011104 *)
> ```

Comment: Could you test also my approach? Not to compete, I don't think it could, but to complete the tests :)

Comment: @Kuba I didn't intend to include timings for all methods.  Anyway, on this test I'm afraid your method doesn't fare well: it takes 33 seconds.  Sadly it's even slower with v length 1500, u length 2500: 300 to 400 times slower than the other two options.  Sorry. :-/

Comment: That's even slower than I've though! ;) But it is not a big surprise :)

Answer (score 8):

Still another way, using rule-based expression rewriting.

```
u /. {i_, j_} -> {{v[[1]], i}, {v[[2]], j}}
```

> {{{0, 1}, {4, 3}}, {{0, 2}, {4, 6}}, {{0, 3}, {4, 9}}}

Comment: i like your solution because it can be easily applied in similar operators.

Answer (score 8):

```
Inner[List, v, #, List] & /@ u

(*  {{{0, 1}, {4, 3}}, {{0, 2}, {4, 6}}, {{0, 3}, {4, 9}}}  *)
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems the most efficient is a pure `Inner` approach unlike in the other answer where it is used with `Map`.

```
Inner[ {#1, #2} &, v, Transpose @ u, List]
```

or simply

```
Inner[List, v, Transpose @ u, List]
```

> ```
> {{{0, 1}, {4, 3}}, {{0, 2}, {4, 6}}, {{0, 3}, {4, 9}}}
> ```

**Edit**

I tested this solution with `tag` instead of `v`, where

```
tag = {a, b, c, d};
```

In the following we compare efficiency of provided resonable solutions.

Let's define:

```
rmrf1[tag_, test_] :=  First@AbsoluteTiming[ Riffle[ tag, #] ~ Partition ~ 2 & /@ test]
rmrf2[tag_, test_] :=  First@AbsoluteTiming[ Thread[ {tag, #}] & /@ test]
trMap[tag_, test_] :=  First@AbsoluteTiming[ Transpose[{tag, #}] & /@ test]
Artes2[tag_, test_] := First@AbsoluteTiming[ Inner[List, tag, Transpose @ test, List]]
MrWizChan[tag_, test_] := First@AbsoluteTiming[Transpose[Tuples@{{tag}, test}, {1, 3, 2}]]
```

Let's choose some sets of data:

```
ts1 = RandomInteger[100, {3 10^5, 4}];
ts2 = RandomInteger[100, {10^6, 4}];
```

now we have:

```
rmrf1[tag, ts1]
rmrf2[tag, ts1]
trMap[tag, ts1]
MrWizChan[tag, ts1]
Artes2[tag, ts1]
```

> ```
> 2.817000
> 1.386000
> 1.577000
> 1.054000
> 0.438000
> ```

and

```
rmrf1[tag, ts2]
rmrf2[tag, ts2]
trMap[tag, ts2]
MrWizChan[tag, ts2]
Artes2[tag, ts2]
```

> ```
>  9.383000
>  4.357000
>  5.051000
>  3.585000
>  1.476000
> ```

These results clearly demonstrate that the `Inner` solution is the best, while the other ones (involving mapping `Thread`, `Riffle`, `Transpose` or transposing `Tuples`) are at least a few times slower. In fact, we get similar results with other data like e.g. `RandomReal`.

Comment: Artes, to be fair you should include timings with a packed array of "tags" i.e. Reals or Integers.  If you do not I will add them to my answer, but I will have to use v7 timings.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard We could restrict to this case since the question didn't concern packed `tags` and the `Inner` is the winner.  Nonetheless I'll try to add those timings later even though they are not stricly related to our problem.

Comment: Well, *this* question does show integer "tags" but I know that the one you originally answered did not.  I think there's plenty of room for both. (Meaning, your optimal method for unpacked data, and Vitaliy's chyanog's and my answers for the packed data.)

Answer (score 6):

yet another idea (works as long as long as the "elements" in `u`, `v` are not `List`s)

```
Function[, {##}, Listable][v, #] & /@ u
```

Answer (score 5):

Again, there is no `MapIndexed` approach:

```
u = {{1, 3}, {2, 6}, {3, 9}}
v = {0, 4}

MapIndexed[{v[[Last@#2]], #1} &, u, {2}]
```

Comment: you are spending a lot of time out here ;) +1

Comment: @Plato Kuba and Michael are burning up the scoreboard; I'm running like a mad man to stay ahead of them. :-)  Oh, and I can't forget Nasser!  This month he's #2.

Comment: @PlatoManiac I have to study for exams and have other duties so the choice is obvious :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard “We are all failures- at least the best of us are.” I am always looking for more and more of this madness of yours! Keep running fast like those quasars :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using the second and third arguments of `Thread`:

```
Thread /@ Thread[{v, u}, List, {2}]
```

> {{{0, 1}, {4, 3}}, {{0, 2}, {4, 6}}, {{0, 3}, {4, 9}}}