# Command to insert item into list

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a command to insert an item into a list such that they form pairs? In other words to take

```
InsertObject[{a,b,c},d]
```

which will output

```
{{a,d},{b,d},{c,d}}    ?
```

This would be equivalent to the function,

```
Table[{{a,b,c}[[i]],d},{i,1,3}]
```

This way works just fine, but it doesn't seem to be the "Mathematica way" of doing things. Is there a built in command this?

Comment: Related: [(3070)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3070/121), [(4004)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4004/121), [(11298)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11298/121), [(13748)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13748/121), [(17381)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17381), [(18213)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18213)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Few* more alternatives:

```
{#, d} & /@ {a, b, c}
Tuples[{{a, b, c}, {d}}]
Join[{#}, {d}] & /@ {a, b, c}
Table[{i, d}, {i, {a, b, c}}]
Append[{#}, d] & /@ {a, b, c}
Prepend[{d}, #] & /@ {a, b, c}
Riffle[{#}, {d}] & /@ {a, b, c}
Distribute[{{a, b, c}, d}, List]
Insert[{#}, d, -1] & /@ {a, b, c}
Replace[{a, b, c}, x_ :> {x, d}, 1]
PadRight[List /@ {a, b, c}, {3, 2}, d]
ArrayPad[List /@ {a, b, c}, {0, {0, 1}}, d]
Partition[Riffle[{a, b, c}, d, {2, -1, 2}], 2]
Transpose[{{a, b, c}, ConstantArray[d, {3}]}]
Transpose[{{a, b, c}, Table[d, {3}]}]
```

**Timings:**

```
f1[lst_, elem_] := Map[{#, elem} &, lst]
f2[lst_, elem_] := Tuples[{lst, {elem}}]
f3[lst_, elem_] := Thread[{lst, elem}]
f4[lst_, elem_] := Join[{#}, {elem}] & /@ lst
f5[lst_, elem_] := Table[{i, elem}, {i, lst}]
f6[lst_, elem_] := Append[{#}, elem] & /@ lst
f7[lst_, elem_] := Prepend[{elem}, #] & /@ lst
f8[lst_, elem_] := Riffle[{#}, {elem}] & /@ lst
f9[lst_, elem_] := Distribute[{lst, elem}, List]
f10[lst_, elem_] := Insert[{#}, elem, -1] & /@ lst
f11[lst_, elem_] := Replace[lst, x_ :> {x, elem}, 1]
f12[lst_, elem_] := PadRight[List /@ lst, {Length@lst, 2}, elem]
f13[lst_, elem_] := ArrayPad[List /@ lst, {0, {0, 1}}, elem]
f14[lst_, elem_] := Partition[Riffle[lst, elem, {2, -1, 2}], 2]
f15[lst_, elem_] := Transpose[{lst, ConstantArray[elem, {Length@lst}]}]
f16[lst_, elem_] := Transpose[{lst, Table[elem, {Length@lst}]}]

funcs = {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14,  f15, f16};
labels = ToString /@ {Map, Tuples, Thread, Join, Table, Append,
                    Prepend, Riffle, Distribute, Insert, Replace, PadRight, ArrayPad, 
                    Partition, TransposeConstantArray, TransposeTable};
res = ConstantArray[0, {16}];

testdata = RandomInteger[10, {10000000}];
Grid[Table[{i, labels[[i]],  First@Timing[res[[i]] = funcs[[i]][testdata, 20];]},
            {i,  Range[16]}], 
     Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

```
And@@(res[[1]] == # & /@ Rest[res])
(* True *)
```

Comment: @eldo, thanks for the vote. I am sure there is at least half a dozen more ways -- e.g. `Through[{a, b, c}[d]] /. x_[y_] :> {x, y}` or `{a, b, c} d /. Times -> List` :)

Comment: +1 I lol'd at wall of ways and the readers digest large print edition benchmark chart ;-)

Comment: @rasher, thank you -- fontsize does indeed look like readers digest style even for my generation:) Still expecting some `BitXor` magic from you though to update the chart:)

Comment: They say imitation is the sincerest form of flattery.  I'm feeling flattered.  :^)

Comment: @Mr.W indeed!  As we have all learned to expect, a totally unexpected idiom is due soon now that this question got your attention :)

Comment: @kguler Sorry to disappoint but I won't be spending time on this.  I think this class of problem has been well covered every before your omnibus answer, and now few stones are left unturned.  I've got *lots* of other things to learn about in the v7 -> v10 transition.

Comment: @Mr.W, btw, congratulations on the v10 license!

Answer (score 8):

Indeed there is:

```
Thread[List[{a, b, c}, d]]
(* {{a, d}, {b, d}, {c, d}} *)
```

or if you like `Thread[{{a, b, c}, d}]` but I thought the first version shows more which function is threaded.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to kguler.

Here are few more.

```
list = {a, b, c};
{list[[#]], d} & /@ Range[3]
{Pick[list, #, 1][[1]], d} & /@ IdentityMatrix[3]
{Extract[list, #], d} & /@ Range[3]
{Take[list, {#}][[1]], d} & /@ Range[3]
Flatten@ReplacePart[{#}, 1 -> {#, d}] & /@ list
Array[{list[[#]], d} &, 3]
{#, d} & @@@ (Transpose@{list})
```